# PHP decrementation loop

Tags: php

I have a string variable like this:  `'1111/222/333'` or `'1111/222/333/444'`

and I want to get an Array like this:

```
111-222-3333
111-222-
111-
```

OR

```
1111-222-333-444
1111-222-333-
1111-222-
1111-
```

I have tried with `$pieces = explode("/", $str);`

and:

```
$str = '1111/222/333/444';
$pieces = explode("/", $str);
for($i=0; $i<count($pieces); $i++) {

    $var .= $pieces[$i]."-".$pieces[$i+1];
    echo $i." - ".$var."<br>";  

}
```

but I haven't gotten the correct result!

Any help?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's French for "loop".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$str = '1111/222/333/444' ;
$pieces = explode("/", $str);
$num = count($pieces);
for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++) {
        print implode('-',$pieces).($i?'-':'')."\n";
        array_pop($pieces);
}
```

[See it work](http://codepad.org/Hc6mexm7)

Comment: What about the trailing hyphens he wants in 2nd to last element?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$str = '1111/222/333/444';
$pieces = explode("/", $str);
$newArray = array();
$s = '';
foreach ($pieces as $piece)
{
    $s .= $piece.'-'
    $newArray[] = $s;
}
rsort($newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

My first try is:

```
$str = '1111/222/333/444';
$pieces = explode("/", $str);
$countPieces = count($pieces);
echo $countPieces;
while ($countPieces > 0) {
    $var = $pieces[0];
        for($i = 1; $i < $countPieces; $i++) {
            $var =  $var . "-" . $pieces[$i];
        }
    echo $var . "\n";  
    $countPieces--;
}
```